# Capacity of a uint64_t?

Tags: objective-c

I have a little problem. Essentially, the code:

```
uint64_t myInteger = 98930 * 98930;
NSLog(@"%qu", myInteger);
```

...just gets it wrong. I get '1197210308' as the output, which is evidently incorrect. Why is this happening? It can't be that a uint64_t is too small, as they apparently go up to [18 and a half quintillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)). Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try casting the first number so the operation is made using that type:

```
uint64_t myInteger = (uint64_t)98930 *98930;
```

Comment: Or: `uint64_t myInteger = 98930UL * 98930UL;`

Comment: Or even better: UINT64_C(98930) * UINT64_C(98930)

Answer (score 8):

98930 is an `int`, so you're multiplying two `int`s, which gives an `int`.  You're then assigning to a `uint64_t`, but it's too late, you've already lost the precision.  Make sure one of the operands is of type `uint64_t`, so the other will be coerced to that type, and the multiplication will be done as `uint64_t` multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about objective-C, but doing the same in C, integer promotions stop at the integer rank, so you get an integer overflow. Try:

```
uint64_t myInteger = 98930LLU * 98930;
```